# VotingClassifier with pipelines as estimators

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, pipeline, ensemble-learning

I want to build an sklearn `VotingClassifier` ensemble out of multiple different models (Decision Tree, SVC, and a Keras Network). All of them need a different kind of data preprocessing, which is why I made a pipeline for each of them.

```py
# Define pipelines

# DTC pipeline
featuriser = Featuriser()
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc_pipe = Pipeline([('featuriser',featuriser),('dtc',dtc)])

# SVC pipeline
scaler = TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance(kind='constant')
flattener = Flattener()
svc = SVC(C = 100, gamma = 0.001, kernel='rbf')
svc_pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),('flattener', flattener), ('svc', svc)])

# Keras pipeline
cnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model())
cnn_pipe = Pipeline([('scaler',scaler),('cnn',cnn)])

# Make an ensemble
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dtc', dtc_pipe), 
                                        ('svc', svc_pipe),
                                        ('cnn', cnn_pipe)], 
                            voting='hard')
```

The `Featuriser`,`TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance` and `Flattener` classes are some custom made transformers that all employ `fit`,`transform` and `fit_transform` methods.

When I try to `ensemble.fit(X, y)` fit the whole ensemble I get the error message:

> ValueError: The estimator list should be a classifier.

Which I can understand, as the individual estimators are not specifically classifiers but pipelines. Is there a way to still make it work?

Comment: is `dtc_pipe` really a `Pipeline`?

Comment: Ups, sorry there was a mistake, I fixed it. I does, however, not change anything. I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the `KerasClassifier`. It does not provide the `_estimator_type`, which was checked in `_validate_estimator`.

It is not the problem of using pipeline. Pipeline provides this information as a property. See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/pipeline.py#L238-L239).

Hence, the quick fix is setting `_estimator_type='classifier'`.

A reproducible example:

```
# Define pipelines
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, Normalizer
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

X, y = make_classification()

# DTC pipeline
featuriser = MinMaxScaler()
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc_pipe = Pipeline([('featuriser', featuriser), ('dtc', dtc)])

# SVC pipeline
scaler = Normalizer()
svc = SVC(C=100, gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf')
svc_pipe = Pipeline(
    [('scaler', scaler), ('svc', svc)])

# Keras pipeline
def get_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


cnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model)
cnn._estimator_type = "classifier"
cnn_pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler), ('cnn', cnn)])


# Make an ensemble
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dtc', dtc_pipe), 
                                        ('svc', svc_pipe),
                                        ('cnn', cnn_pipe)], 
                            voting='hard')

ensemble.fit(X, y)
```