# Stacking Classifier doesn't recognize Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm using a `StackingClassifier` on 5 scikit-learn classifiers and a Keras one. It doesn't seem to recognize the Keras one as a classifier however.

Relevant code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation,  Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras import metrics
import joblib
from joblib import parallel_backend
np.random.seed(42)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
def create_model ():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(best_neurons, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), kernel_initializer=best_init_mode, activation='relu', 
                   kernel_constraint=maxnorm(best_weight_constraint)))
    model.add(Dropout(best_dropout_rate))
    model.add(Flatten())
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=best_learn_rate)
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer=best_init_mode, activation = 'sigmoid'))  # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC(), 'accuracy'])
    return model


NN_clf=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=best_epochs, batch_size= best_batch_size)
RF_clf =RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=best_max_depth_rf, n_estimators=best_n_estimators_rf, 
                               min_samples_leaf=best_min_samples_leaf_rf, max_features=best_max_features_rf,
                               class_weight=best_class_weight_rf, max_samples=best_max_samples_rf,
                               random_state=42, oob_score=True)
KN_clf =KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=best_n_neighbors,  p=best_p, leaf_size=best_leaf_size )
#DT_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=best_max_depth_dt, min_samples_leaf=best_min_samples_leaf_dt)
SV_clf =  SVC(gamma=best_gamma_sv, C=best_c_sv, kernel=best_kernel_sv, random_state=42, probability=True)
GBC_clf =  xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=best_learning_rate_gbc, random_state=42, colsample_bytree=best_colsample_bytree_gbc,
                             max_depth=best_max_depth_gbc, n_estimators=best_n_estimators_gbc,
                            gamma=best_gamma_gbc, subsample=best_subsample_gbc)
EX_clf= ExtraTreesClassifier(max_depth=best_max_depth_ex, n_estimators=best_n_estimators_ex, 
                             min_samples_leaf=best_min_samples_leaf_ex, max_features=best_max_features_ex,
                             warm_start=False, oob_score=True, bootstrap=True, random_state=42)
LR_clf=LogisticRegression(random_state=42, solver=best_solver, penalty=best_penalty, class_weight=best_class_weight, C=best_log_C)

estimators= [('RF', RF_clf), ('GBC', GBC_clf),  ('EX', EX_clf), ('LR',LR_clf), ('KN', KN_clf),
            ('SV', SV_clf), ('NN', NN_clf) ]
clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
print("Stacking model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test.values.ravel()))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-272df6aa838e> in <module>
      2             ('SV', SV_clf), ('NN', NN_clf) ]
      3 clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_jobs=-1)
----> 4 clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
      5 print("Stacking model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test.values.ravel()))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    411         self._le = LabelEncoder().fit(y)
    412         self.classes_ = self._le.classes_
--> 413         return super().fit(X, self._le.transform(y), sample_weight)
    414 
    415     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='final_estimator_')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    129         # all_estimators contains all estimators, the one to be fitted and the
    130         # 'drop' string.
--> 131         names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
    132         self._validate_final_estimator()
    133 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
    247                 raise ValueError(
    248                     "The estimator {} should be a {}.".format(
--> 249                         est.__class__.__name__, is_estimator_type.__name__[3:]
    250                     )
    251                 )

ValueError: The estimator KerasClassifier should be a classifier.
```

I am using Sci-kit learn versions 2.2, TF ver 2.x. I've seen a similar error [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13669) but didn't want to rewrite my code and use the MLextend library.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of the similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897096/votingclassifier-with-pipelines-as-estimators/59915844#59915844) for `VotingClassifier`.

The solution is just adding this `_estimator_type='classifier'` to `KerasClassifier`.

Note: please provide just the minimum code to reproduce your issue.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.constraints import maxnorm

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation,  Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras import metrics
import joblib
from joblib import parallel_backend
np.random.seed(42)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

def create_model ():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    optimizer= keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC(), 'accuracy'])
    return model


NN_clf=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=15, batch_size= 32)
NN_clf._estimator_type = "classifier"

RF_clf =RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, oob_score=True)
KN_clf =KNeighborsClassifier()
SV_clf =  SVC(random_state=42, probability=True)
EX_clf= ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=42)
LR_clf=LogisticRegression(random_state=42,)

estimators= [('RF', RF_clf), ('EX', EX_clf), ('LR',LR_clf), ('KN', KN_clf),
            ('SV', SV_clf), ('NN', NN_clf) ]
clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

X, y = make_classification()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)


clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Stacking model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test))

# Stacking model score: 0.967
```