# Grid-Search Voting Classifier containing a Keras model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a `VotingClassifier` containing a `Keras` model using `GridSearchCV`.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# pretend data
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=20)

scaler = StandardScaler()

# create model
def create_model():   
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation='relu', input_shape=(20,)))
    model.add(Dense(30, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,  activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile model
    optimizer = adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

keras_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model)
keras_model._estimator_type = "classifier"   

eclf = VotingClassifier(
          estimators=[('svc',SVC(probability=True)), ('keras_model', keras_model)]          
          , voting='soft')

#  Test - fit the viting classifier without grid search
eclf.fit(X, y)

print('The VotingClassifier can be fit outside of gridsearch\n')

# parameters to grid search
params = [{'svc__C':[0.01,0.1]}, ]

grid = GridSearchCV(eclf,params,cv=2,scoring='accuracy', verbose=1)
grid.fit(X,y)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The estimator KerasClassifier should be a classifier.
```

When I train the `VotingClassifier` outside of `GridSearchCV` no error occurs, however when I train it within `GridSearchCV`, I get the error message. This other question, [VotingClassifier with pipelines as estimators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897096/votingclassifier-with-pipelines-as-estimators), has the same error (without using GridSearch) and was fixed by a line asserting that the keras model is a classifier which i have also included:

```
keras_model._estimator_type = "classifier"
```

This did not fix the problem here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What keras version are you using? I ran the code you shared (without the `keras_model._estimator_type = "classifier"` line), and I had no problem fitting the VotingClassifier (i.e., it ran just fine). My keras version is 2.2.4, and sklearn is 0.21.2.

Comment: @bqbastos I was using keras version 2.3.1 and scikit-learn version 0.22.2.post1. I downgraded scikit-learn to version 0.21.2 and now it works. Thank you for your help!